# How to use cxf-xjc-ts with ToStringBuilder from lang3?

Tags: java, cxf, xjc, cxf-xjc-plugin

When using the `cxf-xjc-ts` plugin during `xsdtojava`, one can add the property `<extensionArg>-Xts</extensionArg>` to let the compiler generate the following method:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, JAXBToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE);
    }
```

Problem: when having `apache.commons-lang3` on classpath only, the package should be:
`org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder` and using `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.DEFAULT_STYLE`.

Question: how can I tell the `-ts` plugin to actually use the builder from lang3 during generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in `v3.1.0`
@see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXFXJC-16

So now -Xts option is using `lang3`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose to use a bit different approach.

It includes 2 steps to do:

- omit generating default 'toString' methods by xjc plugin - hence it won't use commons-lang (without 3) 'ToStringBuilder',
- use commons-lang3 'ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString' directly where 'toString' is needed.

(during development i've faced undesired usage of 'commons-lang' and my approach provides possibility to skip using 'commons-lang' along with 'commons-lang3').